# Hashmap not being stored into a file?

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

When i debug the code below it throws a `FileNotFoundException` on line                 `properties.store(fos, "none")`, any specific reason for it?

EDIT: By Stack Trace you mean the following then here it is:

```
Exception(Throwable).<init>() line: 249 [local variables unavailable]   
Exception.<init>() line: not available  
Thread.getStackTrace() line: not available  
JCP.WriteVariablesHashmap(HashMap<String,Object>) line: 51  
JCP.NewMethod(String[]) line: 133   
JCP.InteractiveMode(String[]) line: 165 
JCP.BatchOrInterActive(String[]) line: 96   
Main.main(String[]) line: 13
```

### Code:

```
public void WriteVariablesHashmap(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap){
    try {
        File file=new File("Variables.ser");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        fos=new FileOutputStream(file);

        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            properties.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(file);

        properties.store(fos, "none");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace please?

Comment: The [FileOutputStream constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) will throw that exception for various reasons.

Comment: How do you get the complete stacktrace? The code does not reach the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacktrace would be helpful. Also, can you confirm if you have read-write permission in your user directory or if any file called Variables.ser exists. From [Javadocs 1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29),

`if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason`

Comment: Using Java file methods i confirmed that the user has read and write access.

Comment: Can you confirm if there is a file called "Variables.ser" created in your directory? When you do `fos=new FileOutputStream(file);`, it will create file.

Comment: yup i can confirm that.